# MySQL Building/linking tables using index

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I have finished designing the tables structures for a school course catalog. I am using four tables `majors`, `courses`, `course_hours`, `course_date`. Below I have detailed the components of each table. Some of the tables will use indexing based on `course_id`. I am new with database and struggling with building these tables inside my database. How can I make these tables link together with using `course_id`? Or is there a better way to structure these tables for my purpose. If possible providing a query to create these tables will be great.

Hopefully I am using the righ type(`int`,`varchar`, `text`, etc) for my variables.

Example of table **courses**

```
id serial
course_name varchar
course_code varchar
description text
```

Example of table **course_dates** (using index)

```
id int
course_id int
year date
semester int
```

Example of table **course_hours** (using index)

```
id int
course_id int
hours int
```

Example of table **majors** (one to many relationship- index)

```
 major_id int
 course_id int 
 major_name varchar
```

**So a populated database would contain the following:**

Table `courses`

```
course_id course_code course_name       course_description
1     INF1000     Visual Studio I   "Basic programming"
2     INF1001     Visual Stuido II  "More programming"
```

Table `course_dates` (0 for spring, 1 for fall, 2 all year)

```
id course_id year semester
1  1         2012 0
2  1         2013 1
3  2         2013 1
```

Table `course_hours`

```
id course_id course_hours 
1  1         3 
2  1         4 
3  2         4
```

Table `majors`

```
id course_id major_name
1  1         Computer Engineering 
2  1         Information Systems 
3  2         Network Administrator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do some restructuring:

- add hours to courses and get rid of course_hours table (i don't see
  any advantage to extracting hours to a seperate table)
- course_dates might be better named as semester and the fields would be year (int) and semester (int)
- majors should just explain each major so take course_id out and put it into a xref table
- rename all tables to singular form (just a style preference)

giving you a structure like:
[image: ERD]

edit: made it back to a mysql box. here's the script for this structure. remember you might want to change charset and engine type as those can change per database, these are probably fine as is for default

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hours` tinyint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course_semester_xref` (
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `semester_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`,`semester_id`),
  KEY `semester_id` (`semester_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `major` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `major_course_xref` (
  `major_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`major_id`,`course_id`),
  KEY `course_id` (`course_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `semester` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `year` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `semester` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `course_semester_xref`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `course_semester_xref_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`semester_id`) REFERENCES `semester` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `course_semester_xref_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `course` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `major_course_xref`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `major_course_xref_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `course` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `major_course_xref_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`major_id`) REFERENCES `major` (`id`);
```

Comment: This is perfect! I can adapt this to MySQL.

Comment: updated with mysql script, hope this is what you need, and happy databasing!

Comment: Thank you, could you happen to help me write a query that will display all the rows side by side?

Comment: post it as another question, there are plenty of people waiting to show off their query skills. i'll be busy today, but if you want you can link it in a comment here and i'll take a look later and make sure it gets answered

Comment: you might be interested in this [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243626/efficient-query-table-bridge-indexing-and-strucuture) Its pretty much another help with making a query to unite tables.

Answer (score 0):

> Table course_hours
>
> id course_id course_hours
> 1  1         3
> 2  1         4
> 3  2         4

If `course_hours` corresponds to `course_dates, year + semester`, you should integrate it into `course_dates`, because otherwise you cannot link it together and you save an unnecessary additional table.