# Efficient Query, Table Bridge/Indexing and strucuture

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my PhpMyAdmin database I have 9 tables. 8 of those tables are relevant to me at this moment. I would like my queries to be executed quickly enough but I am not sure the design/structure of the tables are the most effecient. Any suggestion of merging a table with another or creating another bridge table?  Also, I am struggling in building a query that will display bridge results from the following tables: `semester`, `schedule`, `office_hours`, `faculty`, `section`, `major_minor`, `major_class_br`, `class`?

[TABLE STRUCTURE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/class_des/)

Basic Query- that shows class details

```
SELECT  class_name, class_caption, class_credit_hours, class_description
FROM class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
select *
from 
schedule 
inner join semester 
on schedule.semester_id = semester.id
inner join office_hours
on office_hours.id = schedule.???
```

It's not clear how office_hours correlates with schedule?

Answer (score 0):

'queries to be executed quickly enough'

INSERT or SELECT?

If you want your INSERT/UPDATE to be fast, normalise it to the nth degree

If you want your SELECT to be fast, denormalise it (which of course makes INSERT's UPDATE's complicated and slow)

If your main table (schedule?) has < 10,000 records and it's a decent RDBMS then it's probably running as fast as it can.

Normally the performance tuning process involves

1. Identifying a workload (what queries do I usually run)
2. Getting a baseline (how long do they take to run)
3. Tuning (adding indexes, changing design)
4. Repeat

So we would really need to have an idea of what kind of queries are performing slowly, or alternatively what kind of growth you expect in which tables.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'bridge results'. What happens when you buidl a query that joins the tables as per the physical diagram? an error or unexpected ersults?

Comment: +1 Thank you, I dont how to build a query that will select all tables in exception of the `events` table.  Can you help build such query?

Comment: what does 'in exception of the events table' mean? Does 'events' have any correlation with the other data? do you want to include or exclude it? What have you come up with so far?

Comment: Oh well you are right `events` table does not have any correlation with the other data. I just want help in making a query that will display all the tables(that have correlation) and their respective values.

Comment: you just join them all up and select the colunms you want? What have you come up with so far?